# Can I still access my Mathematica Kernel after notebook disappears?

Tags: kernel

I am currently accessing a Linux research computer via x2go, and was running a long evaluation on a mathematica notebook there.

Logging back on to check how it was going, the notebook was no longer there, only the initial mathematica start up window. Reopening the notebook appeared to result in a new instance of it.

Using top, I can see that a kernel is still taking up a large amount of memory. I did not set up a specific kernel, and when opening a new mathematica instance the kernel is set just to local.

My question is - can I access the currently evaluating kernel? Or has it crashed, and the memory is just yet to be reallocated?

Comment: This is really a Linux question, and not a Mathematica question. Just rerun the notebook.